# How to Call a C# Function from a Button?

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my application I made some reports with the crystal reports and I used buttons to show my reports (PDF). I want the reports to be open in a new window, not in the same window as the application. I know about the hyperlink's target but how can I call a C# function in the hyperlink's property?

Answer (score 1):

you could try something like...

```
  protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //your code.....
    //then this will open your URL in new window
    Response.Write("<script>window.open('URL/pageName');</script>");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
__doPostBack
```

and check for event target and event argument and call the C# function.

See

[Understanding the JavaScript __doPostBack Function](http://aspalliance.com/895_Understanding_the_JavaScript___doPostBack_Function)

Comment: @adamantium - even if you call the javascript function to invoke the server side method. how can you transfer the resulting output to the new page through the hyperlink button  ???????

Answer (score 0):

Its not that you have to call c# function in Hyperlink property. that cannot be done.

For eg.

If your ReprotMain.aspx is the first page with the button "Click to view"

When you click the button it should show the report in DetailReport.aspx

Then you have to call Write or Call the same method to generate the report in both the 
pages. To prevent the repitation of the code. You can use a Common class to generate report and return to the page. so that is easy to call it. in any page.

Comment: i have the event handler from the button. If I swap the button with a linkButton can i use the target property?(for the _blank, ofcourse)

Comment: It just open the new page but the server method is in the parent page rite. how you will call that method again in the newly opened page ?